# view-based NSBrowser?

Tags: macos, nstableview, nsoutlineview, appkit, nsbrowser

Now that we have `NSTableView` and `NSOutlineView` that can have regular `NSView` objects as their cells, what about `NSBrowser`?  That is can we use regular `NSView` objects as cells in NSBrowser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, not yet

`NSOutlineView` is a subclass of `NSTableView` so both of them got the upgrade to be able to use `NSView` objects as cells in Mac OS X 10.7. This is specifically called out at the beginning of the documentation for `NSTableView`:

> Table views are displayed in scroll views. Beginning with OS X v 10.7 NSView instances (most commonly NSTableCellView instances or a subclass) are supported for rows and columns. Alternatively, NSCell subclass instances can be used for each row and column item.

On the other hand for NSBrowser it says specifically:

> This class uses the NSBrowserCell class to implement its user interface.

Comment: Sad. Sad. Sad. :(     I really would like to have it.